# How to "establish" the basic properties of a commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to "Establish the properties of congruences" as listed in my textbook. These properties are the standard commutative, associative, distributive, etc... properties that follow from proving that $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$ and $[a]\cdot [b]=[a\cdot b]$ are well defined.

How do I go about proving something that looks so obvious? I know the proof that addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is well defined... but how do I prove these basic properties?

- $[a]+[b]=[b]+[a]$
- $[a]\cdot [b]=[b]\cdot [a]$
- $([a]+[b])+[c]=[a]+([b]+[c])$
- $([a]\cdot[b])\cdot[c]=[a]\cdot([b]\cdot[c])$
- $([a]+[b])\cdot[c]=[a]\cdot[c]+[b]\cdot[c]$
- $[0]+[a]=[a]$
- $[1]\cdot[a]=[a]$
- $[a]+[-a]=[0]$

Comment: You just have to use that addition and multiplication are commutative on the real numbers (particularly the integers). That's it.

Comment: See [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring). It follows directly from the definitions.

Answer (score 2):

As an example, here is how you prove $[a]+[b]=[b]+[a]$: $$[a]+[b]=[a+b]=[b+a]=[b]+[a].$$
(The first equality is the definition of $[a]+[b]$, the second equality is the fact that addition of integers is commutative, the third equality is the definition of $[b]+[a]$.)